# Problems Converting to Evo PDF

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using version 8.0.0 of "EvoPdf.HtmlToPdf.NetCore" package in my project. When I try to get the radar canvas image as pdf output, I am not successful. The pdf output is blank. I don't think there is any problem in the code we created the canvas. I am using Chart.Js version 2.9.3 for radar canvas.

The same problem exists when I want to convert "https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/area/radar.html" to pdf with "https://www.evopdf.com/demo/" help. Canvas is not drawn in pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this official article：

[https://www.evopdf.com/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx](http://%20https://www.evopdf.com/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx)

You can download the code samples provided by him according to the asp.net core you use.

It currently only seems to support .net core2 and 3 versions.